# Bypassing "ghost" line break or end of file (EOF) in data.table::fread

Tags: r, error-handling, dataframe, data.table

I'm loading several large, tab-delimited text files exported from an (accessible to me) database into R using `data.table::fread`.  `fread` handles most of the files with great ease and speed, but one of the files is generating a regularly-reported `fread` error:

```
Error in fread(read_problem, encoding = "UTF-8", na.strings = "", header = TRUE,  : 
                   Expected sep ('  ') but new line or EOF ends field ...
```

A smaller (2000 rows) version of the file containing the offending line is available here ([RDS file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0srJaKm5SW_UVBBdkJjZHFoa1U/view)).

Here's how I've tried to diagnose the problem to this point:

```
library(data.table) # I'm using 1.9.7 development (same error with 1.9.6)
read_problem <- readRDS("read_problem.rds")
error <- fread(read_problem, encoding = "UTF-8", na.strings = "",
               header = TRUE, sep = "\t", 
               colClasses = rep("character", 44),  # For simplicity
               verbose = TRUE)
```

If I excise the offending line, the problem disappears:

```
cat(read_problem, file = "temp")   
string_vec <- readLines("temp")
clipped_vec <- string_vec[-1027] # Get rid of problem line 1027
restored <- paste(clipped_vec, collapse = "\n")
noerror <- fread(restored, encoding = "UTF-8", na.strings = "",
                 header = TRUE, sep = "\t", 
                 colClasses = rep("character", 44)) # For simplicity
class(noerror)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

dim(noerror) 
[1] 1999   44
```

The error message seems clear enough: `fread` is looking for a "\t" but is finding something else in its place.

But I find nothing obvious from a closer look at the offending line relative to those around it.

The number of tab characters is the same

```
sapply(gregexpr("\t", string_vec[1026:1028]), length)
[1] 43 43 43
```

Line break information seems identical

```
unlist(gregexpr("\n", string_vec[1026:1028]))
[1] -1 -1 -1
```

Here's a look at the offending line itself as a string:

```
string_vec[1027]
[1] "URN:CornellLabOfOrnithology:EBIRD:OBS132960387\t29816\tspecies\tNelson's Sparrow\tAmmodramus nelsoni\t\t\t1\t\t\tUnited States\tUS\tGeorgia\tUS-GA\tGlynn\tUS-GA-127\tUS-GA_3181\t\t\tJekyll Island\tL140461\tH\t31.0464993\t-81.4113007\t1990-11-03\t13:15:00\t\"Jekyll Island and Causeway. Partly cloudy, mild, NE wind 8-15 mph. Note: Did very little birding in upland habitats as time available was rather brief.\"  Data entered on behalf of Paul Sykes by Alison Huff (arhuff@uga.edu) on 12-15-11.\tListed on old Georgia Field Checklist as \"Sparrow, Sharp-tailed.\"\tobsr289931\tPaul\tSykes\tS9336358\teBird - Traveling Count\tEBIRD\t270\t8.047\t\t1\t1\t\t1\t0\t\t"
```

Any advice to get around this problem without the manual extraction of offending lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With with [this commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/3398e5dccde78f22b611459897b125ef1908049f), this is now fixed in [v1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), current development version. The next stable release should therefore be able to read this properly using `quote=""`.

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.7+
fread('"abcd efgh." ijkl.\tmnop "qrst uvwx."\t45\n', quote="")
#                    V1                V2 V3
# 1: "abcd efgh." ijkl. mnop "qrst uvwx." 45
```

---

On the 1027th line, at the end of `"Sparrow, Sharp-tailed."` there's only one tab. Where as in the other lines, after that field, there are two before the "obsr[0-9]" field starts.

The number of tabs seem to match because, on line 1027, there's a tab before "Listed on old Georgia Field" instead of a space..

Therefore line 1027 gets only 43 cols instead of 44. This seems to be the issue.

---

Looking at this again, it seems like `Listed on old Georgia Field Checklist as "Sparrow, Sharp-tailed."` should be read as a separate column but instead is being read together with the previous column...

Here's a smaller reproducible example:

```
# note that there are only 2 instead of 3 columns
fread('"abcd efgh." ijkl.\tmnop "qrst uvwx."\t45\n')
#                                     V1 V2
# 1: abcd efgh." ijkl.\tmnop "qrst uvwx. 45

# add a header column and it returns the same error
fread('a\tb\tc\n"abcd efgh." ijkl.\tmnop "qrst uvwx."\t45\n')
# Error in fread("a\tb\tc\n\"abcd efgh.\" ijkl.\tmnop \"qrst uvwx.\"\t45\n") : 
#   Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) 
#   ends field 1 when detecting types (   first): "abcd efgh." ijkl.    mnop 
#   "qrst uvwx."    45
```

Filed [1367](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1367).

Comment: Thanks very much @Arun.  You're correct in that the "Listed on old Georgia..." belongs in a separate field ("SPECIES COMMENTS") whereas the other records are empty in this field.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to:

1. Read all CSVs into one list

   df<-lapply(csv, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

Each element of the list represents one CSV

2. Convert list into one big dataframe

df2 <- ldply(df, data.frame)

3. Remove row containing EOF using grep as usual.

df3<-df2[!grepl("eof", df2$V1),]

where V1 is the column name where EOF is.

Answer (score 0):

For this error of "Expected sep ('|') but new line or EOF ends field 6 on line 8863 when reading data:"

you need to just add additional quote="" in the fread code

fread(load_file_from_directory, sep = "|",quote="")